# concatenate results after multiprocessing

Tags: pandas, multithreading, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a function which is creating a data frame by doing multiprocessing on a df:-

Suppose if I am having 10 rows in my df so the function processor will process all 10 rows separately. what I want is to concatenate all the output of the function processor and make one data frame.

```
def processor(dff):

    """
    reading data from a data frame and doing all sorts of data manipulation 
    for multiprocessing
    """

    return df


def main(infile, mdebug):

    global debug
    debug = mdebug

    try:
        lines = sum(1 for line in open(infile))
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error {} opening file: {}").format(err, infile)
        sys.exit(2000)

    if debug >= 2:
        print(infile)

    try:
        dff = pd.read_csv(infile)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error {}, opening file: {}").format(err, infile)
        sys.exit(2000)

    df_split = np.array_split(dff, (lines+1))

    cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    cores = 64

    # pool = Pool(cores)
    pool = Pool(lines-1)

    for n, frame in enumerate(pool.imap(processor, df_split), start=1):
        if frame is not None:
            frame.to_csv('{}'.format(n))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
"""
print "Debug is: {}".format(args.debug)
"""
if args.debug >= 1:
    print("Running in debug mode: "), args.debug

main(infile=args.infile, mdebug=args.debug)
```

Comment: what have you tried?  why is your code writing to csv files?  why are you reading `infile` twice rather than just seeing how many rows you loaded?

Comment: Where I am reading twice? and the code which I have pasted I tried but it's just going into a loop and erroring out

Comment: the code in each `try` block effectively rereads the file.  `len(dff)` would be a shorter and less error prone (and faster) way of getting the number of rows

Comment: okay! I get it yeah I can improve that but that's not where I got stuck its the contamination of pandas which is troubling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use either the [data frame constructor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) or [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to solve your problem.  the appropriate one to use depends on details of your code that you haven't included

here's a more complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create dummy dataset
dff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(101, 5), columns=list('abcde'))

# process data
with Pool() as pool:
  result = pool.map(processor, np.array_split(dff, 7))

# put it all back together in one dataframe
result = np.concat(result)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'split_array'

Comment: @abhi oops!  thanks have corrected to `array_split`